# Referencing file with relative path under referenced Jar file

Tags: java, jar

We have a selenium test framework developed using Java. All selenium related common functions are developed as separate project and created a jar file. The common library file has the chromedriver.exe file placed under src/main/resources. When the jar is created the chromedriver.exe is placed directly under jar. In a class file under this jar we have code to load the driver exe at run time

like
case "ie":

```
webdriverFile = "IEDriverServer_32.exe";
```

case "chrome":

```
webdriverFile = this.getClass().getResource("chromedriver.exe").toString();
```

We referenced the jar in separate project created for writing test cases which is named as 'testcases'. When i try to run the tests, the code under the switch statement is looking for the driver.exe files in path relative to the testcases project and hence it always end up file not found.

How do we correct the code under switch statements to look for the exe files under the jar and not on calling project. Any help would be great

Comment: Is the jar containing the executable included in the classpath?

Comment: Thank you for respone.We have not added this jar in class path. Having a clarification around how to add the class path. 
The Commonlibrary Jar which we have problem in mapping is depending on multiple other jars (selenium,autoit,many more).How to add the class path for the Commonlibrary jar so that it refers to all other dependent jars and resources within itself, when called from callign project 'testcases'
Eg:
Commonlibrary.jar
       |-- chromedriver.exe
       |-- IEdriver.exe
       |-- AutoIDX3.dll
       |-org\openqa\selenium\....
       |--jersey\repackaged\com\google\common\base
etc.